# ReferenceError: ko is not defined when loading from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to load *KnockoutJS* using the *jQuery*'s `getScript` function and, after countless tests, I'm still stuck with the

> ReferenceError: ko is not defined

error.

Here's a simple code that I'm running in my script to test if everything works (I've also tried to write this code directly into *FireBug* but I got the same results):

```
$.getScript('http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.2.0.js', 
    function(d,s,j){
        console.log(d);
        console.log(s);
        console.log(j);
        console.log(ko);
});
```

Checking the console shows those messages:

> undefined
>
> success
>
> Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success", other elements...}
>
> ReferenceError: ko is not defined

and I've no idea on what's going on.

As a side note, I've also tried those urls with the same results

- http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js
- http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.2.0.debug.js

EDIT:

Based on @T.J. Crowder's first answer I also tried this code

```
$("<script>")
.on("load", function() {
    // It's loaded now
  console.log("success");
})
.on("error", function() {
    // It failed to load
  console.log("error");
})
.attr("src", "http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.2.0.js");
```

but nothing is shown on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) uses XHR (ajax), which is controlled by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). So you can't load scripts from other origins unless they enable your origin via [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/).

Instead, simply add a `script` tag referencing the script you want to load.

```js
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.onload = function() {
  display("Loaded: " + typeof ko);
};
scr.onerror = function() {
  display("Error");
};
scr.src = "http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.2.0.js";
document.querySelector("script").parentNode.appendChild(scr);

function display(msg) {
  $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm loading both *Bootstrap* and *BootstrapSwitch* with this code and I've got no problems but I'll try your code and see what happens

Comment: @StepTNT: All that means is that their CDNs let you do that. See the links.

Comment: Just tried the code that you removed with a slight edit and added it to the question.

Comment: @StepTNT: For reasons I'm not getting, the jQuery version loaded the script but never fired the event. The non-jQuery version (added above) works correctly. Very odd. (If you need to support really old versions of IE, also add an `onReadyStateChange` handler and look for `readyState === 4` on the script element. But modern IE uses `load`.) (I've been loading scripts this way for years, but don't think I ever happened to have coded it using jQuery rather than just using the DOM directly before.)

Comment: @StepTNT: I've tested the snippet above on Chrome, Firefox, IE11, and [this page](http://jsbin.com/waged) on iOS Safari (Snippets don't show a run button on iOS Safari, I'm surprised to find). I get "Loaded: object" on every single one of them, as expected. As I said, I've been loading scripts this way for years. It works (modulo old IE, as I said aboe).

Comment: I've given up, I can't get it to work and I know that your reply is correct so there's nothing more that I can do.